# how to declare default constructor

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a Base class that I can't modify the source code. I make a derived class from it and I am trying to make a no-argument constructor for this derived class. The problem is that I can't define the constructor for two reasons:
There is not a non-argument constructor defined for the base class to use it.
I can't pass a default value for the constructor of the base.

```
  class base
  {
      public:
      base (A arg)
      {

      }
  };

  class derived : public base
  {
      public:
      derived () : base (arg)  //ERROR
      {

      }
  };
```

Is there a solution to define a non-argument constructor for the derived class? 
Cordialement,

Comment: You've got no choice but to come up with a suitable `A` object that you can pass to the constructor of `Base`.

Comment: No. You need to find a way to pass an `A` object to `base(A)`.

Comment: _"I can't pass a default value for the constructor of the base."_ - Why not? Is this some artificial limitation or do you not know how?

Comment: Even if it was possible, why do you want to do that? The "Base part" of the Derived object would be garbage, possibly landing you into UB territory. You might as well pass some default argument to the Base constructor, and then *not* use it in the Derived code, if that's what you intend to do.

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot change the base class the only option left is to pass an argument to its constructor. You can do this quite easily by constructing a temporary instance of `A` and passing it to the base class in your ctor initialized list of derived classes.

```
derived::derived () : base (A())
{
}
```

In the code above `base(A())` will create a temporary instance of `A` and pass it to the constructor of `base`.